# Why did H.264, MPEG-4 HE AAC stop working on iphoneXS/Max?

Tags: h.264, h.265, aws-elastictranscoder, iphone-xs, iphone-xs-max

**Issue regarding NEW hardware**

I have been investigating like crazy, and haven't found any hints to why my H.264 encoded videos have stopped working on these new devices.

Context: Direct from the ios device, the original is sent to s3, aws elastic transcoder then encodes the original into a more compressed H.264 preset. As of yesterday, a coworker was reporting all videos being "black", now since deliveries on these devices are being fulfilled, i've gotten confirmation. Cannot reproduce this issue on simulator. The encoded videos that are not playing, i've listed the exif data below.

Is there is anyone out there with a domain expertise in codecs, can you weigh in why a new device would fail to decode this H.264 video when devices since iphoneX and below have no problem?

```
➜  Downloads exiftool 30B3485D-24A3-4B6D-8B27-15B7C11FB864.mp4
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.10
File Name                       : 30B3485D-24A3-4B6D-8B27-15B7C11FB864.mp4
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 202 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:09:24 20:35:47-07:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:09:24 20:36:02-07:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:09:24 20:35:53-07:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : MP4
File Type Extension             : mp4
MIME Type                       : video/mp4
Major Brand                     : MP4  Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
Minor Version                   : 0.2.0
Compatible Brands               : isom, iso2, avc1, mp41
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Modify Date                     : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Time Scale                      : 1000
Duration                        : 4.12 s
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Track Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 4.12 s
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 100.00%
Balance                         : 0
Audio Format                    : mp4a
Audio Channels                  : 2
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Image Width                     : 320
Image Height                    : 568
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Media Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
Media Time Scale                : 15360
Media Duration                  : 4.00 s
Media Language Code             : und
Handler Description             : VideoHandler
Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
Op Color                        : 0 0 0
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 320
Source Image Height             : 568
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Bit Depth                       : 24
Pixel Aspect Ratio              : 1:1
Video Frame Rate                : 30
Handler Type                    : Metadata
Handler Vendor ID               : Apple
Encoder                         : Lavf57.71.100
Movie Data Size                 : 202178
Movie Data Offset               : 4545
Avg Bitrate                     : 393 kbps
Image Size                      : 320x568
Megapixels                      : 0.182
Rotation                        : 0
```

Comment: You say videos are black, but is there any audio being played?

Comment: Unfortunately i have no physical access to these devices to repro with yet. I found a friend with the device and doing sanity tests which can be confirmed via iMessage quickly. Good point on audio, will dig in more.

Comment: If you're curious, this is the asset that can't be played from these new devices https://vout.getspar.com/afe7bd79-4465-4fb6-8f86-d39b26db7002/F0368F15-4962-4377-8FCB-5F2EF0807FEA.mp4  The elastic transcoder H264 preset is `InterlacedMode:Auto,MaxReferenceFrames:3,Level:4.1,ColorSpaceConversionMode:None,Profile:high`  I've done other sanity tests, transcoded HEVC playing fine, the original source, in this case `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality`  with `AVAssetExportSession` working fine.

Comment: Audio is: AAC, Profile:HE-AAC, sample: auto, bitrate: 40, channels: auto. The players on these devices must be having issues decoding with one of my settings, but i'm having trouble narrowing it down. Works fine on every other apple device I have. ios11/12, iphoneSE/X/7/8, ipad pro/mini. I wonder if it's something unique to the encoder AWS is using. I feel like other content providers would be chirping about this by now.

Comment: Any update on this? Having similar issues.

Comment: I found that there is a community who also discuss this issue. https://community.arlo.com/t5/Arlo/iPhone-XS-Max-On-IOS-12-Is-Not-Playing-Videos-In-Library/td-p/1636309/page/25 It seems that the issue was solved after updated to iOS12.1, but It didn't work for me. Any update?

Comment: Any update on this? Having similar issues. Mine is also iOS12.1

Comment: Anyone got any tips for this?  I have the same issue for iphoneXS at iOS12.2...  black video, audio works.  Videos play on all other models of iPhone I've tested on

Comment: I never came back to this, I used it as an excuse to switch over to CMAF https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/about_the_common_media_application_format_with_http_live_streaming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug resolved itself for me in iOS13 beta release.  Apple got back to me and informed me that the H264 header said that my video was version 4.0 but the first H264 frame says that it's 3.1, and iOS12 will not allow that.

I was able to fix this in code by specifying my header version as 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this with black video on iPhone XS Max, and it turns out that I was setting the keys `kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey` and `kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey` to YES in the `sourcePixelBufferAttributes` dictionary when creating the `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`. Commenting out those two keys from the dictionary seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the reason. IPhone Xs+ supports all of the H.264 resolutions and frame rates. However certain frame rates require HEVC:

- 1080p @ 240 fps
- 4K @ 60 fps

Thus if you won't configure the captureSession.sessionPreset to some custom - lower resolution values:

```html
if isFullHDVideoEnabled && captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080)  {
                    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
                }
                else {
                    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720
                }
```

iPhone will capture a video in H.265, and there would be the only option (.hevc) in movieFileOutput.availableVideoCodecTypes.

```html
                    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                        if movieFileOutput.availableVideoCodecTypes.contains(.h264) {
                            movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264], for: connection)
                        }
                        else if movieFileOutput.availableVideoCodecTypes.contains(.hevc) {
                            movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc], for: connection)
                        }
                    }
```